# After loading data from one cluster to another w/ sstableloader, is there a way to verify table contents are complete in new cluster?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Say I want to copy a table from Cluster A to Cluster B, and I do so with sstableloader on each Cluster A node (after flushing). Is there any way for me to verify that the table in Cluster B contains all of the contents in Cluster A?

I'm running Cassandra 2.0.15.

Answer (score 0):

A script that `select *`'s from both probably easiest. Or using `COPY TO` in cqlsh on both and comparing the CSV.

Especially if Cluster B has a different topology then Cluster A (very likely if you use vnodes) you cant just compare the sstables, hashes or anything. There is no "cross cluster repair".